# Java Web Start Applet opening new Browser Window/Tab ignoring target

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, java-web-start

Having successfully migrated an applet to a java webstart applet, I notice that every call to

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(
new URL("http://"+ host+ "/" + filename + language + ".htm"),
 "Helppage");
```

opens a new browser window (Win 7/MSIE11) or tab (firefox depending on configuration) though I obviously request a specific named possibly already open browser window.

Has anyone successfully managed to redirect those calls to one browser window (tab)? If yes, how?

Looks a similar context to [How do I close a browser window that was opened by Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780756/how-do-i-close-a-browser-window-that-was-opened-by-java-web-start)

- Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to solve this using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). A short explanation can be found in [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37964967/3776810)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaims! I think customer has arranged with the situation but I will definitely have a close look in case this comes up...